# mpv player crashes if Intel tearfree is turned on

Tags: xorg, 20.04, intel-graphics, tearing, mpv-media-player

I'm using mpv on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I was facing screen tearing when playing videos, therefore to fix this I enabled the "TearFree" option by adding the following line to the configuration file: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"

  Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

But after doing so the videos wouldn't play at all. mpv crashes everytime with 'Segmentation fault'. If I revert the changes it would play again but the screen tearing reappears.

Output of lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] [1002:6820] (rev 81)
```

Comment: Hi gorlomi! Can you give us a bit more info about your system/setup? What GPU do you have? (You can find it under System Settings > Info or by typing `lspci | grep VGA` into a terminal.) Have you tried different media players, e.g. VLC? (Install that from the Ubuntu Software Center.)

Comment: I already had VLC deb version installed which too was crashing. I uninstalled it and tried the snap version of VLC.Snap version is working fine

Comment: Thanks a lot! Same problem here (Lenovo T580)

:) gelma ~ $ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case, I created the same file with the contents mentioned in Arch Wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight#xbacklight). And my mpv start crashing with segfault.

Comment: Opened an issue about this https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/9559

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/9559) in mpv repository and it turned out that the problem is not about mpv but my drivers.

Try this:

```
MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965 mpv some_video.mp4
```

If it works, congratulations. You can create a script to pass this option and use that script instead of directly using mpv. Do not forget to make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
/usr/bin/mpv "$@"
```

And [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/9559#issuecomment-986269285) is the related part from Github issue for this answer. You might find some useful information even if above commands didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Great news, that the snap version of VLC works! If that's a workable workaround for you, perfect, just leave it at that.

Should you want to investigate the root cause further, you can look at these two things:

- The snap version of VLC working could be down to it using a different video output. You can check (and change) the video output in VLC under `Tools > Preferences > Video > Output`.
- Another factor in your case could be your dual GPUs. It's not immediately apparent which GPU is the culprit in your case. You could try to identify which card is active when the tearing happens and then try to investigate further. However, in my experience, troubleshooting dual GPU issues can lead you down very deep rabbit holes. So if you are happy with using the VLC snap, you might just want to leave it at that.